# Adding fractional part to a TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, timestamp

How can I add the fractional part to a TIMESTAMP. I tried this and it didn't seem to work.

```
 CREATE TABLE t(A TIMESTAMP);

 INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES (
DATE '2022-04-01' + INTERVAL '18:02:42.123456' HOUR TO SECOND);

SELECT * from t;

A
01-APR-22 06.02.42.000000 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES (
  TIMESTAMP '2022-04-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '18:02:42.123456' HOUR TO SECOND);
```

When you add in `INTERVAL` to a `DATE` then the result is converted to `DATE` which does not support fractional seconds, see [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i48042)